# Centos 6 : scrapy commend not found(installed successfully)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, scrapy

I guess it because I installed new python2.7 on CentOS 6.

Background:
 I installed python2.7 on my CentOS 6, but keep python 2.6 of system because my yum is based on python 2.6, and I set python 2.7 as default by:

```
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7.12/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Then install new pip for py2.7 and set default by:

```
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7.12/bin/pip2.7 /usr/bin/pip
```

last I install scrapy by : `pip install scrapy`, it success!

But in terminal I run: `scrapy -V` it throw：

```
-bash: scrapy: command not found
```

I guess the scrapy need to be `ln -s` too as default for system, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it the scrapy which I installed located:

```
/usr/local/python2.7.12/bin/scrapy
```

But there is no scrapy in system bin folder, so I need to add up path to system path, so I run the command:

```
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7.12/bin/scrapy /usr/local/bin/scrapy
```

After that, when I need to run scrapy, system will find it in path `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`, and then go to the path `/usr/local/python2.7.12/bin/scrapy` and find the real scrapy, so it works for me now.